# Loading Nested collection in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have belowe Classes:

```
1- PurchaseMaster :Has collection >> PurchaseDetail
2- PurchaseDetail :Has Product
3- Product
```

I want get PurchaseMaster with Detail and Product . I try with belowe queries but Its return error :

```
var purchaseMasterModel = _purchaseMasters
        .Include("StoreMasters.Details")
        .Include("ProductHeader")
        .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Code == code);

var purchaseMasterModel = _purchaseMasters
        .Include("StoreMasters.Details")
        .Include("StoreMasters.Details.ProductHeader")
        .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Code == code);

var purchaseMasterModel = _purchaseMasters
        .Include("StoreMasters.Details")
        .Include("Details.ProductHeader")
        .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Code == code);
```

I getting this errors:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'DataLayer.Context.StoreDetail' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'ProductHeader'.
>   my classes like this :

```
public class PurchaseMaster:BaseEntity
 {
  public virtual ICollection<PurchaseDetail> PurchaseDetails { get; set; }
 }



 public class PurchaseDetail:BaseEntity
   {
     public PurchaseMaster PurchaseMaster { get; set; }
     public Guid PurchaseMasterId { get; set; }
     public ProductHeader ProductHeader { get; set; }
     public Guid ProductHeaderId { get; set; }
    }

public class ProductHeader:BaseEntity
{
   public virtual ICollection<PurchaseDetail> PurchaseDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Why not use the include overload which takes a property selector? `.Include(x => x.SomeProperty)` ?

Comment: how ? can you tell  please?

Comment: You should show us your class definition so we can help.

Comment: What is `StoreMasters`?

Comment: @Domysee each `StoreMaster` has `PurchaseMaster`

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `_purchaseMasters`?

Comment: @Domysee its like `IDbSet<PurchaseMaster> _purchaseMasters;`  `_purchaseMasters = _uow.Set<PurchaseMaster>();`  and `     private readonly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already selecting `PurchaseMaster`, so you should not specify `StoreMaster`.

You also have to use the property names. `ProductHeader` has a property *PurchaseDetails*, but not *Details*.

The following query should work:

```
var purchaseMasterModel = _purchaseMasters
        .Include("PurchaseDetails")
        .Include("PurchaseDetails.ProductHeader")
        .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Code == code);
```